# Can Windows installer install two msi files at the same time?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a msi installation package made by WIX, which automatically installs IIS Express 10.0 after the installation.

```
<Binary Id="myCustomActionsDLL" SourceFile="$(var.CustomAction.TargetDir)CustomAction.CA.dll" />
<CustomAction Id="CheckIISExpressStatus" BinaryKey="myCustomActionsDLL" DllEntry="CheckIISExpressStatus" Execute="immediate" Return="check" Impersonate="yes"/>
<CustomAction Id="InstallIISExpress" BinaryKey="myCustomActionsDLL" DllEntry="InstallIISExpress" Execute="immediate" Return="ignore" Impersonate="yes" />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="CheckIISExpressStatus" After="InstallFinalize" Overridable="yes">NOT Installed</Custom>
  <Custom Action="InstallIISExpress" After="CheckIISExpressStatus" Overridable="yes">NOT Installed AND IS_INSTALL_IISEXPRESS="1"</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

In the InstallIISExpress action, I call bat to perform the installation.

```
msiexec /i iisexpress_amd64_en-US.msi /qb
```

But during execution, the Windows Installer prompts the error:

**Other programs are being installed, please wait for the installation to complete, and then try again to install the software.**

What parameters can I set to allow msi to install two msi at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

You must not run other setups from a custom action within your main MSI. Instead **you should run MSI files in sequence using a bootstrapper such as [WiX's Burn feature](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/)**.

It is late. I tried to write a proper explanation of this at one point, maybe see if it makes sense to you: [Wix - How to run/install application without UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48148875/wix-how-to-run-install-application-without-ui/48157650#48157650).

To summarize: running legacy setup.exe files from a custom action in your MSI will not be reliable, and running MSI files - whether directly or embedded in a setup.exe will positively not work because Windows Installer does not allow concurrent MSI installation sequences. [A mutex is set when InstallExecuteSequence runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49258206/wix-custom-action-sequence/49310996#49310996), and no other InstallExecuteSequence can be run while it is in effect. **Concurrent MSI installations are forbidden and technically impossible**.