# Trying to add 3rd party exe to existing msi created by windows installer project

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-installer

I created a windows installer project for a WPF application which should also installer a 3rd party driver.exe and another 3rd party tool(another windows application) xyz.exe along with my MSI file created. So, I add both the 3rd party driver and tool to the commit actions. I want to install my WPF application 1st and then the driver and followed by 3rd party tool.

Currently, my WPF application is installing good followed by the driver. But when it is trying to install it is giving me an this error "There is a problem with this windows installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor."

Comment: That error usually indicates a problem with a custom action. MSI files can not be installed concurrently, they should be run one after the other in sequence. [See this answer for more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49503544/129130). There are methods to create **`setup.exe`** files that install MSI files, prerequisites and other types of setups. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52446750/removing-default-dialogs-from-msi). Essentially WiX Burn bundles, Installshield Suite projects, Advanced Installer launchers, etc... [Burn sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52071758/129130)

Comment: [**MSI Logging**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54458890/129130) can help to determine more about the custom action problem.

Comment: Yes, The MSI's cannot be installed concurrently. I had to create a WIX bootstrapper project which includes all the MSI's I need and use that as my installer. Thank you for your time @SteinÅsmul